# supplying inputs to stdin programatically line by line?

Tags: c++, c, windows, scripting, command-line

I have a test program which prompts for input from user(stdin), and depending on inputs, it asks for other inputs, which also need to be entered.

is there a way I can have a script do all this work ?

Comment: It's completely possible but the question sounds too general.

Comment: I wish I could downvote a comment. +1 to the question -- sounds like a good use case for acceptance tests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a program called [expect](http://sourceforge.net/projects/expect/) that does pretty much exactly what you want -- you can script inputs and expected outputs and responses based on those outputs, as simple or complex as you need.  See also the [wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect) for expect

Comment: to add: I found a book called `Exploring Expect`, which is pretty good.

Answer (score 1):

I may have misunderstood, but do you have a program which reads the input and does something with it, and you just want to know how to automate providing it some test input?

For a given test case, does the input you provide have to depend on the output from the program, or is it the same every time?

If the input for a given test is the same every time, then just put it in a text file and redirect stdin for your program to read from that file:

```
myprogram.exe < input.txt
```

If the input is different each time, for the same test, then this doesn't help. But for a typical simple test, you just want to answer "y" to the first question, "n" to the second, and "hello world" to the third, or whatever.

Comment: Steve, the program is interactive, with many combinations. not possible to manually input everything, that too every time we run it.

Answer (score 0):

In the general case, [yes](http://www.perl.org/), [there](http://python.org/) [is](http://www.ruby-lang.org/).

For more specific tasks, you can get other tools to do the job that will be more specialized and usable for that particular task.

Comment: can you please provide a simple example in any one of them ? if possible.

Comment: @Gollum: I would need a specific problem statement with specific inputs and outputs. Can you provide that?

Comment: sure, if I say _foo.exe_ is asks _enter your file name :_ now I need to enter the file name, then asks me _enter the type of test_ .....
I want to put all these answers in one file or some script which does that automatically?  But I do not want to waste your time, I am learning expect too. so its okay if you have to spare extra time for this.